# How to remove unconverted data from a Python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a database of mostly correct datetimes but a few are broke like so: `Sat Dec 22 12:34:08 PST 20102015`

Without the invalid year, this was working for me:

```
end_date = soup('tr')[4].contents[1].renderContents()
end_date = time.strptime(end_date,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
end_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(end_date))
```

But once I hit an object with a invalid year I get `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 2`, which is great but im not sure how best to strip the bad characters out of the year. They range from 2 to 6 `unconverted characters`.

Any pointers? I would just slice `end_date` but im hoping there is a datetime-safe strategy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah, I'd just chop off the extra numbers. Assuming they are always appended to the datestring, then something like this would work:

```
end_date = end_date.split(" ")
end_date[-1] = end_date[-1][:4]
end_date = " ".join(end_date)
```

I was going to try to get the number of excess digits from the exception, but on my installed versions of Python (2.6.6 and 3.1.2) that information isn't actually there; it just says that the data does not match the format. Of course, you could just continue lopping off digits one at a time and re-parsing until you don't get an exception.

You could also write a regex that will match only valid dates, including the right number of digits in the year, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: +1, chopping off the excess is the best approach.  Here is a fairly simple one-liner to do the same thing: `end_date = end_date[:end_date.rindex(" ")+5]`

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, that's a much better way.

Comment: Doesn't work for '2021-05-13T23:30:52.000Z'. Kindly don't post anything as a generic solution without verifying.

Answer (score 35):

Unless you want to rewrite `strptime` (a very bad idea), the only real option you have is to slice `end_date` and chop off the extra characters at the end, assuming that this will give you the correct result you intend.

For example, you can catch the `ValueError`, slice, and try again:

```
def parse_prefix(line, fmt):
    try:
        t = time.strptime(line, fmt)
    except ValueError as v:
        if len(v.args) > 0 and v.args[0].startswith('unconverted data remains: '):
            line = line[:-(len(v.args[0]) - 26)]
            t = time.strptime(line, fmt)
        else:
            raise
    return t
```

For example:

```
parse_prefix(
    '2015-10-15 11:33:20.738 45162 INFO core.api.wsgi yadda yadda.',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
) # -> time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=15, tm_hour=11, tm_min=33, ...
```

Comment: Nice to remove exactly is left over without too many assumptions.

Comment: Could also replace `time.strptime` with `datetime.datetime.strptime` for a datetime object, as requested.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an even simpler one-liner I use:

`end_date = end_date[:-4]`

Answer (score 6):

Improving (i hope) the code of Adam Rosenfield:

```
import time

for end_date in ( 'Fri Feb 18 20:41:47 Paris, Madrid 2011',
                  'Fri Feb 18 20:41:47 Paris, Madrid 20112015'):

    print end_date

    fmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
    try:
        end_date = time.strptime(end_date, fmt)
    except ValueError, v:
        ulr = len(v.args[0].partition('unconverted data remains: ')[2])
        if ulr:
            end_date = time.strptime(end_date[:-ulr], fmt)
        else:
            raise v

    print end_date,'\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

`strptime()` really expects to see a correctly formatted date, so you probably need to do some munging on the `end_date` string before you call it.

This is one way to chop the last item in the `end_date` to 4 chars:

```
chop = len(end_date.split()[-1]) - 4
end_date = end_date[:-chop]
```

Comment: This is pretty good too but I probably wont remember it as easily as kindall's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
ReportingDate = struct[7][1:-1] # 6/21/2022 5:00
dt = ReportingDate[:-5] # 6/21/2022
ReportingDate1 = datetime.strptime(dt, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).