# Converting dates with times like "midnight"

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have the following string which I am trying to convert to a datetime in python

From django template I am getting the following date format:

July 1, 2013, midnight

I am trying to convert the string above into a date time format

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(x, '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
```

It throws a format error

time data 'July 1, 2013, midnight' does not match format '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p'

Comment: Post your code so we can review it. Show what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: That example doesn't really explain the format. Will it always say midnight afterwards? Could it say something else (and does it matter since it's just the time)?

Answer (score 3):

#### Your best shot is probably the [parsedatetime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime) module.

Here's your example:

```
>>> import parsedatetime
>>> cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
>>> cal.parse('July 1, 2013, midnight')
((2013, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 245, 0), 3)
```

`cal.parse()` returns a tuple of two items. The first is the modified `parsedatetime.Calendar` object, the second is an integer, as explained in the docstring of the `parse` method:

- 0 = not parsed at all
- 1 = parsed as a C{date}
- 2 = parsed as a C{time}
- 3 = parsed as a C{datetime}

#### A few words on `strptime`:

`strptime` [won't be able to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5045210) "midnight", but you can replace it with an actual hour, using something like this:

```
def fix_dt(raw_date):
    """Replace 'midnight', 'noon', etc."""
    return raw_date.replace('midnight', '0').replace('noon', '12')

def parse_dt(raw_date):
    """Parse the fuzzy timestamps."""
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(fix_dt(raw_date), '%B %d, %Y, %H')
```

Then:

```
>>> parse_dt('July 1, 2013, midnight')
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 1, 0, 0)
```

You can play on [strfti.me](http://strfti.me/) to see which one will match your format.

You should check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1258712). The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258858) suggest using [parsedatetime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime) and [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing) to parse fuzzy timestamps like the one in your example. Also check [this pyparsing wiki page](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/UnderDevelopment).

Answer (score 0):

You could also just combine the date withe datetime's start time:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
dt = date.today()
print(datetime.combine(dt, datetime.min.time()))
```