# How to match arbitrary characters in a str when formatting datetime in Python?

Tags: python, string, datetime, format, match

I want to convert a string to a datetime in Python. But there are some characters, which are irrelevant in the String.

[Python Datetime Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Is the official document, there is no clear way to match arbitrary characters in the String.

---

For example, I have a String `2018-01-01Ajrwoe`.

I want to convert this string into a datetime as `2018 (year) 01 (month) and 01 (day)`.

The rest of this string is irrelevant.

- I know that I can change the string (remove the irrelevant characters) first like

```py
raw_str = "2018-01-01Ajrwoe"
my_str = raw_str[:10]
strptime(my_str, my_format)
```

- But I just want to directly match the arbitrary characters like

```py
raw_str = "2018-01-01Ajrwoe"
strptime(raw_str, my_format)
```

- But how is `my_format`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime strptime - set format to ignore trailing part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284850/datetime-strptime-set-format-to-ignore-trailing-part-of-string)

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5045374/11703358

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using a regex to clean your string :

```
raw_str = "2018-01-01Ajrwoe"

datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub('[a-z|A-Z]', '', raw_str), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Output :

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the date using a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

For example:

```
import re
raw_str = "2018-01-01Ajrwoe"
match = re.search(r'\d+-\d+-\d+', raw_str)
print(match.group(0))
```